# Exception Entity Is Already Being Tracked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm getting an error for tracking the sane model but I don't know how else to access the model and save the changes. The error reads like this:

```
        System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'UserMetaData' cannot be tracked 
    because another instance with the same key value for {'UserId'} is already being tracked. When attaching
     existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider 
    using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.'
```

The code that is crashing my site is this:

```
public IActionResult ConsentForm(string holder)
{
    var id = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserId");
    var userId = new Guid(id);
    var userMetaInfo = _elearnContext.UserMetaData.Where(u => u.UserId == userId).SingleOrDefault();


    UserMetaData userMetaData = new UserMetaData
    {
        UserId = userId,
        Consent = userMetaInfo.Consent,
        Location = "",
        CanChangePassword = true
    };
    _elearnContext.UserMetaData.Add(userMetaData);// crashes here 
    _elearnContext.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account");
    // return View("~/Views/Home/ConsentForm.cshtml", ConsentData);
}
```

I think the problem is that before I call this function I am using the same access in the former function like this:

```
public IActionResult RedirectToConsentForm(string controllerName, string actionName)
{

    var Id = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserId");
    var UserId = new Guid(Id);
    var UserMetaInfo = _elearnContext.UserMetaData.Where(u => u.UserId == UserId).SingleOrDefault();


    if (UserMetaInfo.Consent == true)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ConsentForm", "Account");

    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction(controllerName, actionName);
    }

}
```

If any one has any ideas please let me know.

Comment: what are you trying to do with `UserMetaData`? It does not look like you want to update it but looks more like you want to clone some existing data? But cloning such data in this case makes no sense. At least we need your confirmation about that.

Comment: im redirecting a user to a page if the consent boolean is not true then giving the user the opption to change the checkbox to true if they want. I am putting those other datatypes in because they are set to not null in the database. @KingKing

Comment: it's still unclear what you're trying to do with `UserMetadata`, suppose if it's existed, you need to update it. But here it also may be that you want to clone it. When you design the table for `UserMetadata`, you need to know it thoroughly, about its purpose, how the data is added (in which cases?) and how the data is updated (in which cases?). Looks like you're not even sure about that. So it's hard to fix the code.

Comment: as in the code you posted, if `UserMetadata` need to be updated, the only updated property seems to be `CanChangePassword` (updated to `true`), it's unclear why `Location` is set to `""` in that case. In other words, it's confusing to guess if it's being updated or being cloned.

Comment: the boolean Consent is the only one that has the ability to change on this HTML page with a check box. I had to set the other data because I was getting an error because they were Null and my table does not let these values be null. where I think someone could help is by letting me know if there is another way I can get the consent from the user metadata table to use to test if it is true I am just four weeks into ASP.NET so I'm very unsure of everything.@KingKing

Comment: I've just added an answer, tried to keep it as simple as possible. Actually almost what you will learn here is how you handle this case of updating an entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scenario in this case is actually update the metadata if existed otherwise add a new one. It crashes because after querying for the metadata, it's tracked (`AsNoTracking` is not used). Then that tracked entity is added to the context and causes the error. Here's how it should be:

```
var userMetaInfo = _elearnContext.UserMetaData.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserId == userId) ?? new UserMetaData();
if(userMetaInfo.UserId == 0){
  //set the consent only at the time creating a new metadata
  userMetaInfo.Location = someLocation;
  userMetaInfo.CanChangePassword = true;
  //add the new entity to the context (mark it as added)
  _elearnContext.UserMetaData.Add(userMetaInfo);
}
//now set this to update the consent which should be true
//because this code is run only after the user accepted (redirected from another action)
userMetaInfo.Consent = true;

//finally save the changes
_elearnContext.SaveChanges();
```

Note I'm not sure about what you set for the `Location` (and when to update it). So it depends on your logic. But it looks like in the code above the only thing you want to update is the `Consent` property and it must be `true`. Although we check for the `UserId` to know if it's being creating a new metadata but I believe that at that time, the metadata may already have been created (somewhere else). However it's the general logic we process it in this case (something like adding the entity only if there is no existing data, otherwise update the properties on the fetched and tracked entity).